# How to fit a 4 dimensional array to a 2 dimensional array for sklearn SVM

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, svm

I'm running into some problems when attempting to create an VSM:

```
EEG.shape = 41, 73, 64, 1000
stimpresent = 41, 1000

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(EEG,stimpresent)
```

If i run this it gives me the following error: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
On the internet people have recommended others to reshape the array using numpy. but if i try this:

```
EEG.shape = 41, 73, 64, 1000
EEGSVM = EEG.reshape(41,73*64*1000)
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(EEGSVM,stimpresent)
```

it gives the following error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [41, 1000]

does anyone know how to fix this, or if it is even possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In short, the issue is with the shape of `stimpresent` which should be flat and represent the discrete classes of your input data.

[SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) is a classifier that takes a 2D matrix as training input data and an array (1D) as target values, with `X_train.shape[0] == len(y_train)`.

Given the volume and shape of your data and the heaviness of its computation, I doubt that SVC is what you need.

Comment: I have indeed made a mistake there. stimpresent is now a 1 dimensional array, which method can i use to fit a 4D matrix in this case?